# Otrs refresh ticket status view

Tags: otrs

I wanted to know if it was possible to enable or implement a feature that help to refresh automatically the status view of the tickets.

I was thinking about an AJAX plug-in or an implementation, or something like that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTRS already has this feature. Go to your user settings and configure the "Refresh interval":

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot. But now I'm asking if it possible to trigger the display of a new ticket when it's change of status or queue, ect...

Comment: Not that I know of.